# Hole in blender is covered in slicer

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I'm trying to print old petrol station and there is a hole for "petrol pistol". In blender, everything looks good. But when I exported to OBJ or STL and open it in Prusaslicer, there are many errors, but the hole is still there. After automatic correction of errors in the slicer, the hole is covered. I have tried several things in Blender (but I'm a newbie) but nothing helps. Of course, I can send the blender file but I can't see any possibility to attach it to this topic.

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much in advance.
Kind regards,
Roman

Comment: I'm not sure where is the hole you're talking about, but usually when a holes is filled in external program it means you didn't triangulate the model when exporting it. In the export tab you have an option to triangulate, you should enable it